# vb.net linq update Data

Tags: vb.net, web-services, linq-to-sql, vb.net-2010

Hi Guys thanks for all the help on things. Im using linq and im able get get data ouf of it realy easy. but i seem to not be able to update the data. the program does not error on it and it looks likes it has updated but it does not save te changes.

```
 Public Function UpdateAlarmsbyKey(ByVal objKey As Integer, ByVal IdNumber As String) As Boolean
    Dim lqAlarms As New linqAlarmDumpDataContext

    Dim GetAlrms = From r In lqAlarms.AlarmDrops _
                   Where r.Key = objKey _
                   Select r


    For Each Calls In GetAlrms

        If Calls.AlarmsHandled = "" Then
            Calls.AlarmsHandled = IdNumber
            Return True
        Else
            Calls.AlarmsHandled = Calls.AlarmsHandled & ":" & IdNumber
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling -

```
lqAlarms.SubmitChanges()
```

after you've updated the `Calls.AlarmsHandled` property. Also, your code is looping round a result set but will only change the first record it finds, is that the behaviour you wanted?